# could not convert string to float: 'December'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm running the following python script

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
data = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/g81bupjm6r3ir7p/hotel_bookings.csv?raw=1', index_col=1 )
X = data
y = data.loc[:,'previous_cancellations']
data.head()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test =  train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model=LinearRegression();
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

However I got the error when trying to fit a linear regression model, please help.

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-59-4719cf73997a> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(x_train,y_train)

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'December'
```

Comment: For linear regression your X should include numbers only. One methods to select number columns is ```X = data.select_dtypes('number')```. For real task you should consider normalization techniques and also convert string data to numbers (if it makes sense in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `X` variable (and consequently your `x_train` variable) is a pandas DataFrame of 31 columns of various data types, including strings. I'm assuming you want your `X` to be only one specific column from the dataset, and therefore you should do `X = data['column_name']`.

If you choose a column that has strings in it, you regression still won't work, you will need to convert it either to numbers (January = 1, February = 2, ...), vectors (January = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], February = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], ...), datetimes, or something else that is regression-friendly.